# autocomplete google address is crashing in android

Tags: android, google-api, autocompletetextview

I am implementing the code below from this link [Android - AutoCompleteTextView only works when backspacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857334/android-autocompletetextview-only-works-when-backspacing/17862403#17862403)

but I am getting error .I have posted the logcat error below:

Also I have created class :

```
public class SimpleAddress {

    public SimpleAddress(String formatted_address, Double lat, Double lng) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getFormatted_address() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

But I guess its not correct .Please help me resolve this issue:Using new googleapis instead of old one.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Logcat error:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: , PID: 498
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1585)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1167)
    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:554)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1096)
    at .MainActivity$AdapterUpdaterTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:190)
    at .MainActivity$AdapterUpdaterTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 185 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: Log.i("ADDED", simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address()); but I have commented it

Comment: @Raghunandan I ran the project again now its showing this error.Let me know if there is abetter way to make this work?Thanks Raghu for looking into it.

Comment: what is line 190 `MainActivity.java` ?

Comment: autoText.showDropDown();

Comment: @jason post `MainActivity.java` and also specify that line.

Comment: @jason `simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address()` is null for line 185

Comment: I have commented that and dropdown code .But still its not working .Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: @jason Look at `MainActivity.java` line 190. see if something on that line is null and post the code

Comment: @Raghunandan autoText.showDropDown(); this is the code at 190.

Comment: @jason `autoText` is null

Comment: checking it now also my SimpleAddress class is wrong I guess, can you please look into it .Sir I would really appreciate any help .

Comment: @Raghunandan Basically I want http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=wal&sensor=false&components=country:US to keep showing address as every character is entered.I am getting the response but its crashing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you sent a link to is a big mess, see my answer in this thread instead [How to dynamically add suggestions to autocompletetextview with preserving character status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara)

Comment: Thanks.Basically I want http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=wal&sensor=false&components=country:US to keep showing address as every character is entered.I am getting the response but its crashing .

Comment: I tried the code you provided and the layout is outside and autocomlpletetextview is huge .How do I ssign it to right id.I mean can you show the xml? Thanks for the help again.

Comment: you dont know how to write layout.xml ?

Comment: I created LinearLayout and Autocompleletetextview and findviewbyid to those @+id but its crashing .Can you please help me out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42667/discussion-between-jason-and-pskink)

Comment: I have posted the query in chat