# Auto suggestion for city and area

Tags: android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I created this little app where the city and area is asked to the user. Once the user enters the city, the area auto suggestions should get refined and suggest only the areas present in that particular city. I am using one city array by name "cities" and many other arrays which stores the areas in different cities for that corresponding city. EX: if the city selected is "abc"  I have one another array with name "abc" containing the areas in the city abc.
How do I refine the search for area once the city has been entered, so that only area corresponding to the entered city is auto suggested?  Do I need to use switch case?

The java file

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);

    this.text1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
     String[] city = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCity = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);
    this.text1.setAdapter(adapterCity);
    this.text1.setThreshold(1);


     this.text2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.area);
     String[] area = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Agra);
     // In place of the array "Agra" the feed from text1 has to be used.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterArea = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, area);
    this.text2.setAdapter(adapterArea);
    this.text2.setThreshold(1);

    }
```

The string.xml

```
//array for the cities
<string-array name="cities">
    <item>Agra</item>
    <item>Aurangabad</item>
    <item>Bilaspur</item>
    <item>Vraranasi</item>
    </string-array>
```

//area array for the city Agra

```
<string-array name="Agra">
    <item>Agra-HO</item>
    <item>Abc</item>
    <item>Def</item>
    <item>Ijk</item>
   </string-array>
```

//area array for the city Aurangabad

```
<string-array name="Aurangabad">
    <item>Abc</item>
    <item>Def</item>
    <item>Ijk</item>
     </string-array>
```

Shall I use switch case(It would take a longer code involving cases for all the cities) or there's an inbuilt class, function for the same?

Comment: Just want to make sure I have this correct. Say theres three arrays. Cities, City1, and City2

Cities=[City1,City2]
City1=[abc,cbd]
City2=[jdf,iui]

So the user picks something from 'cities' and gets the elements from the city they selected?

Comment: Yeah you got it correct ollien, once city1 is selected how do I get to to attach city1 in statement `String[] area = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Agra);` in place of "Agra"? As this statement demands the array name.

Comment: Why not use a Hashmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The simple solution is add an onTextChange for text1.
   In it's afterTextChanged function init text2 with the correct adapter (check it's value before etc.).
2. The more correct solution would be to extend an adapter for text2 and implement a filter that would return the correct areas you need. see here for more info
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862403/1393632.   Replace the filter that approaches the web with your own logic

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Could you please put up a little code for the same.